# creating a list of tuples (x, y) from a string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string of the form:

> POLYGON ((159.5 534.5, 157.5 535.5, 157.5 554.5, 155.5 557.5,...))

I want to convert it to a list of tuples like this:

> [(159.5, 534.5), (157.5, 535.5), (157.5, 554.5), (155.5, 557.5), ...]

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't, at least give it a bit of time - you'll learn more than just asking for a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945856/converting-string-to-tuple-and-adding-to-tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like an option you can try this:

```
data = "POLYGON ((159.5 534.5, 157.5 535.5, 157.5 554.5, 155.5 557.5))"
print [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in data.replace('POLYGON ((', '').replace('))', '').strip().split(', ')]
```

Or without list comprehension:

```
data = data.replace('POLYGON ((', '').replace('))', '').strip()
res = []
for rec in data.split(', '):
    res.append(tuple(float(val) for val in rec.split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)\s([\d\.]+)', the_string)
[('159.5', '534.5'), ('157.5', '535.5'), ('157.5', '554.5'), ('155.5', '557.5')]
```

Then just convert each item to float